# Replacing Data in exe file at a marker in Java

Tags: java

I have an exe file which when you open in text mode has this data 
`SUBID:$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$` somewhere before Digital Signatures.

I want to replace these `$` with some string value `subID` like `SUBID:1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLM` without breaking the digital signature of file. *(Doing this replacement manually doesn't break the digital signature)*.

What I am doing now is :

1. Reading the content of the exe file in a String variable `FileContents`.
2. Get the index of `SUBID` in the `FileContents`,
3. Substring the `Filecontents` from 0 to `indexOf ("SUBID")` into a new String `copyStr`
4. Append `"SUBID:"+subID` in `copyStr`
5. then append the remaining content of the `FileContents` in the copyStr
6. And finally converting the string back into byte form and make exe
   as following:

   ```
   String fileContent = readFile("MySetup.exe", Charset.defaultCharset());
   int index_subid = fileContent.indexOf("SUBID");
   String copyStr =fileContent.substring(0, index_subid);
   copyStr += "SUBID:" + subID;
   copyStr += fileContent.substring(index_subid + "SUBID:".length()+ subID.length());
   InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(copyStr.getBytes());
   ```

   //Function readFile()

   ```
   public  static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
             throws IOException 
   {
   byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return encoding.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(encoded)).toString();
   }
   ```

But the problem is although the replacement of data is happening correctly, My resulting exe is getting corrupted, may be because of conversion from byte to text.

So is there any other way I can replace the data after `SUBID` marker in the exe ?

Comment: I would not edit a binary file in text mode.

Comment: What would you do then ?

Comment: Open a binary file using a class lile [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html).

Comment: Most proable cause is String. Dont use string for search/replace. Read the file into a byte array and then traverse that array to replace the string.